# Fisher exact text and connection between Binomial and Hypergeometric distributions.

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

My textbook shows the connection between binomial and hypergeometric using the fisher exact test.."Assuming the null hypothesis and letting p=p1=p2, we have $X$ ~ $Bin(n,p)$ and $Y$ ~ $Bin(m,p)$, indepedently, so $X+Y$ ~ $Bin(n+m,p). Thus,

$$\Pr(X = x \mid X + Y = r) = \dfrac{{m \choose r-x}p^{r-x}(1-p)^{m-r+x}{n \choose x}{p^x}(1-p)^{n-x}}{{n+m \choose r}{p^r}(1-p)^{n+m-r}}$$

results in $\dfrac{{n \choose x}{m \choose r-x}}{n+m \choose r}$, a Hypergeometric distribution.

I don't understand how they got from the LHS to the RHS of the equation.

Answer (score 0):

So is this all that you're asking:

You have this: $$\Pr(X = x \mid X + Y = r) = \dfrac{{m \choose r-x}p^{r-x}(1-p)^{m-r+x}{n \choose x}{p^x}(1-p)^{n-x}}{{n+m \choose r}{p^r}(1-p)^{n+m-r}}$$

So what we can do first is to simplify the numerator and get: $$\Pr(X = x \mid X + Y = r) = \dfrac{{m \choose r-x}p^{r}(1-p)^{m-r+n}{n \choose x}}{{n+m \choose r}{p^r}(1-p)^{n+m-r}}$$

Now you can cancel terms from the numerator and denominator: $$\Pr(X = x \mid X + Y = r) = \dfrac{{m \choose r-x}{n \choose x}}{{n+m \choose r}}$$

Which looks like a Hypergeometric Distribution. Is this what you were asking?

Comment: No I don't understand how you get from 
$$\Pr(X = x \mid X + Y = r)$$ to $$ \dfrac{{m \choose r-x}p^{r-x}(1-p)^{m-r+x}{n \choose x}{p^x}(1-p)^{n-x}}{{n+m \choose r}{p^r}(1-p)^{n+m-r}}$$

Comment: Honestly I've never dealt with the Fischer exact test. I've tried to look into it and see how that formula fits into it. I'll look in my stats book now and see if I can find it and I'll get back to you!